# Why is my DC motor making a rattling scraping sound?

Tags: dc-motor, sound

The DC motor on my hob extractor fan is making a rattling and scraping sound when I switch it on. I know it is coming from just the motor because I have tried running the motor on its own. What could be causing this sound? How can it be fixed? Thanks!

Comment: Can tie turn the motor shaft by hand? Have you inspected the brushes and brush holders?

Comment: Is the motor old enough to have cracked bearings? Please examine the motor in detail. We cannot do that for you.

Comment: Something fell into it, or something inside of it broke.  Does it have ventilation holes?  Can you peer inside to see if everything looks normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its almost always bearings. chances are if its scraping already, they'll be right full of tiny metal filings in the grease. If you have the luxury of being able to dissassemble it somewhat, check them all with an IR thermometer or similar, the hot one is the one you want to fix, but perhaps you should give them all a little grease for longevity's sake.

then pull the bearing (there are tools, but sometimes you just have to get creative), and just find the same bearing again online... just like electronics, everything's marked and described on the part... or there's a datasheet.

I'll entertain the possibility of the brushes being worn out too, but that tends to result in near total failure rather than rattling and scraping